# Adding a new method to the Kynetx Twitter Module

Tags: api, twitter, krl

Hey Kynetx guys, what is the procedure to request a new method be added to the Twitter Module?

I'd like to submit an app for this latest contest, but I need a method added. What say ye?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do Thom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send off an email to support@kynetx.com with the functionality you are wanting to add, why you want it added, and a code example of what you propose the syntax be for the added functionality.